# How can I change the Java version for my Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Plugins need to be configured to build against specific JDK version.
How can I change the version of Java that my plugin uses?

Comment: A plug-in can't use a different version of Java from the rest of the application. It can specify a minimum version that it requires.

Comment: As @greg-449 already said, the minimum Java version can be set in the `MANIFEST.MF` e.g. with a line like `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8`. But as far as I know there is nothing for the maximum version (which might be a problem when things are not only added but also removed from the JRE which is the case since Java 9). Since a Plug-in project is an extended Java project you can configure a specific JRE in _Project > Properties_ (which I guess will be ignored when using Tycho for building).

Comment: may I update a plugin or reinstall it to increase the minimal version?

Comment: Updating a plugin (with a new version number) can change its settings. Note that the plugin will not be run if it requests a version of Java higher than the one being used to run the app.

Comment: Some of the plugins are configured to build against JDK 1.6, although my machine is by default bundled with JDK 1.8. Could I force them to be built against v 1.8?